# Using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem for Millions of threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I have the need to process millions of files.  Currently, I use a custom thread manager to do the work by using a DataGridView to keep track of the threads and a timer to check if more threads can start; kind of like (sudo):

```
Private Sub ThreadManager()
    If AVailableThreads > 0 then
        Dim t as Threading.Thread = New Thread(AddressOf MyThread)
        t.Start()
        AvailableThreads = AvailableThreads - 1
        ThreadManager()
    End If
End Sub
```

This has many drawbacks, the main ones being that the CPU and memory usage is high as each of the above threads process a full directory instead of each file independently.

So I have rewritten the process.  Now I have a class that will perform the process at the file level and report back to the main thread the results; like so:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class ImportFile

    Public Class ImportFile_state
        Public ID as Long = Nothing
        Public FilePath as String = Nothing
        Public Result as Boolean = False
    End Class

    Public Event ReportState(ByVal state as ImportFile_state)

    Dim _state as ImportFile_state = New ImportFile_State

    Public Sub New(ByVal ID as Long, ByVal FilePath as String)
        MyBase.New()
        _state.ID = ID
        _state.FilePath = FilePath
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetInfo()
        'Do the work here, but just return the result for this demonstration
        Try
            _state.Result = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            _state.Result = False
        Finally
            RaiseEvent ReportState(_state)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above class works like a charm and is very fast, uses almost no memory and next to nothing of the CPU.  Albeit that I have only been able to test this with a few hundred threads using the Threading.Thread process.

Now I would like to use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to execute the above class for each file allowing the system to control the number of threads to have running at any given time.  However, I know I cannot just dump several million threads into the ThreadPool without locking up my server. I have done a lot of research on this and I have only been able to find examples/discussions on using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem for a few threads.  What I need is to fire off millions of these threads.

So, I have two questions: 1) Should I even be trying to use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to run this many threads, and 2) is the code below sufficient to perform this process without locking up my server?

Here is my code so far:

```
        For Each subdir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath)
            For Each fl In Directory.GetFiles(subdir)
                'MsgBox(fl)
                Dim f As ImportFile = New ImportFile(0, fl)
                AddHandler f.ReportState, AddressOf GetResult
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf f.GetInfo))
                ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(worker, io)
                Do While (worker) <= 0
                    Thread.Sleep(5000)
                    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(worker, io)
                Loop
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: You are getting this pretty wrong.  Threads are a nice way to keep multiple processor cores busy.  But that's not what they are doing, they are all fighting over the disk, trying to read a file.  Especially a spindle disk hates that, disk reader head seeks are the most expensive thing you can ever do.  Effective throughput will be considerably less.  Only use *one* thread to read files.  If any post-processing is necessary that involves calculation then you can do that with multiple threads.  Use a BlockingQueue to distribute the work.

Comment: "few hundred threads" ?  You should have 1 thread to read from the harddrive, put the data in a queue. Have X number of thread (equal to the number of core - 1 on the cpu) to handle the queue.

Comment: I can see where you two are going (I need to change the process path of my application), but neither comments address either of the underlying questions:  Should I be considering the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem as my thread manager for millions of small threads (to the point you two were making, I would need to add a line that reads the file and then spins up a thread to process the data) and will the code I provided not lock up my server?

Comment: What do  you hope to accomplish by spawning a million threads?  It's doubtful that you would be able to create that many anyway.  Even though there is probably no theoretical limit, you will likely be limited by Windows itself.  I think the limit is around 2000 threads due to the default stack size for a thread.  If you create too many threads, then your code will spend more time doing context switches than doing real work!

Comment: I am not attempting to start a million threads all at once @ChrisDunaway.  I have about a million files that I need to process and, I hope, the last code snippet above will not allow more than the ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads.  Therefore not starting any more threads until there are available threads.

Comment: Is there no one who can answer this??

Comment: I have had no luck in getting a true answer to either of the questions.  For anyone else who may have a similar issue, I can say that the suggestions by @HansPassant and the_lotus worked to my advantage.  In my case, the processing of the file performs a lot faster than the reading of the file.  So I read a file, process it and the processing has completed before the reading of the next file.  My ThreadPool available threads never decreases by more than 1.